# Drawing.Image Not allowed in Moq or Unit Test?

Tags: c#, image, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm attempting to unit test a method that loads an Image (of type Image, not the file path) onto a Virtual machine stack.

I have a `Verify` call that looks like this:

`mockVM.Verify(q => q.Stack.Push(It.IsAny<Image>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());`

In order to check wether the following `Stack.Push` call occurred in the method under test. The pertinent parts of this method are thus:

```
Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"" + Operands[0]);
VirtualMachine.Stack.Push(newImage);
Console.WriteLine("Hit loadimage");
```

In the class under test I am using `System.Drawing` perfectly fine in order to use Image as a type.

However in the Unit test code, despite using `System.Drawing` or any variant, I get an error under Image in `It.IsAny<Image>()`.

> The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I want to verify that an object of type image was placed on the stack, but not being able to use `Image` as a type is a problem and I can't progress.

Is there some reason why I can't use `System.Drawing` in the unit test? Or is there an easy way to achieve my aim.

Comment: isn't the syntax of It.IsAny... `It.IsAny<Image>()`?

Comment: Was just changing it as I type, yes. Good catch though.

Comment: you say you're getting an error, but did not specify your error

Comment: @James Is this a compile time or run time error?

Comment: Intellisense flags it as not existing in the current context. The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok that's compile. you may be missing a reference. Take a look at @Kritner 's answer. he seems to have figured out your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Drawing` is likely not an included by default as a reference of your unit test project, where it would most likely be included by default for other project types.

Ensure you have a reference to `System.Drawing` in your unit test project, then you should be able to resolve `Image` after using the appropriate namespace.

Example using default references for a new project and unit test project:

[image]

Comment: Bang on the money. It wasn't generated in the UnitTestProject references by default where it was for the project under test. Manually adding it to references allowed me to use `using System.Drawing;` and now compiles fine. Much appreciated.